Why $\mathbb A^{n+m}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb P^n\times \mathbb P^m$
Via Segre embedding $\mathbb P^n\times \mathbb P^m\to \mathbb P^{(m+1)(n+1)-1}$ it is a projective variety etc. However I cannot understand how this embedding embeds $\mathbb A^{n+m}$ as an open subset. They state it as trivial fact in an algebraic geometry book.
Edit:
Serre embedding is defined as follows:
$$\mathbb P^n\times \mathbb P^m\to \mathbb P^{(m+1)(n+1)-1}\\ (x_0:\cdots:x_n),(y_0:\cdots:y_m)\mapsto (z_{0,0}:z_{0,1}:\cdots:z_{n,m})$$
Where $z_{i,j}=x_iy_j$
It can be shown that this map is morphism of varieties and image of this map is a closed subvariety of the range and any subclosed variety of the image is given by zero locus of some bihomogeneous polynomials.

Can you see why $\mathbb{A}^n$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Yes ofc, say $x_0\neq 0$

So $\mathbb{A}^n$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{P}^n$ and $\mathbb{A}^m$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{P}^m$. Now you can combine these two to produce an open subset of $\mathbb{P}^n\times\mathbb{P}^m$.

The question in the title does not match the question in the body. The image of $\mathbb{A}^{n+m}$ under the Segre embedding will certainly not be open.

Open subset of the image!

Thank you for the comments. The trick with $\mathbb A^n\to \mathbb P^n$ is a bit subtle here. By the construction of the serre embedding above (see the edit on the question) $\mathbb A^{n+m}$ is identified with the non-zero locus of $z_{ij}=x_iy_j$ for any $i,j$. (In particular you can say $\mathbb A^{n+m}\simeq {(z_{0,0}:z_{0,1}:\cdots:z_{n,m});|; z_{0,0}\neq 0}$)
